# How do you create a three part conditional render using react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I am trying to create a conditional render and seem to be messing up somehow. Is this possible?

`` location: `${props.off_campus_location ? ( `${props.off_campus_location}` ) : ( `${props.campus_location.name}` ) : ( `${props.location_type}` )}`, ``

Error I am getting:

> Unexpected token, expected "}" (15:118)

Comment: What do you mean by 'render'? It looks like you are trying to create a dynamic expression which would require the infamous insecure `eval()`.

Answer (score -1):

You're trying to use ternary operators with invalid syntax. The [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) have a great explanation for how this construct should be used.

You could use a sequence of `||` operators to render the first truthy value in the sequence, like this:

```
location: `${props.off_campus_location ? ( `${props.off_campus_location}` ) : ( `${props.campus_location.name}` || `${props.location_type}` )}`
```

Although I think what you're trying to accomplish would be much cleaner if you just used an `if` statement, but of course, that's personal preference.

Answer (score -1):

For whatever it is worth I usually just move these out to a helper method

```
class SomeComponent extends React.Component {
   render() {
     const someProp = this.state.someProps

     const someComplexStatement = () => {
       if(someProp === 1) {
         return (<span>1</span>)
       } else if (someProp === 2) {
         return (<span>2</span>)
       }
     }
     return (
       <div>
         { someComplexStatement() }
       </div>
     )
   }
}
```

You can move this to a class method, some other component, whatever makes sense. The ternary operators are a bit hard to read for my tastes so I try to clean it up a bit. There's no "right" answer here, but if I'm going more than a simple `if/else` I try to avoid them.